# Bash text absolute positioning

Tags: bash, position, absolute

How can you do absolute positioning of output? Very similar to like when Linux first boots and you see the following:

```
Starting process blah blah blah                              [   OK   ]
```

Comment: do man `printf` and read about string formatting

Comment: Another method is to use [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to position the cursor explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the code used to produce those `[  OK  ]`  in many Linux distributions in `/etc/init.d/functions`

```
$ grep echo_ /etc/init.d/functions
echo_success() {
echo_failure() {
echo_passed() {
echo_warning() {
$
```

Upon inspection, you will see that those function use [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

```
echo_success() {
  [ "$BOOTUP" = "color" ] && $MOVE_TO_COL
  ...
  return 0
}

MOVE_TO_COL="echo -en \\033[${RES_COL}G"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "tput cup 10 10" to move the cursor to desired location. In this case 10th column and 10th row.
Check out the tput's man page.

Comment: The problem with all of these is it moves the entire prompt.

Comment: Actually this may work. How do I only specify the horizontal position?

Comment: It can be done by: "tput cuf N".

Check out the documentation at [TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html).

The page also contains a lot of examples, you can also use tput to find out the terminal dimensions so with that information it should be pretty easy.