# Move cursor position in bash at specific column

Tags: bash, escaping, echo, ansi-escape

I want to move the bash cursor in an echo command on a specific column, but without changing the line. What I have so far is:

```
this.echo('NONE found on ' + accountName + '(' + accountPos + ')' + '\033[30f !!!');
```

I want the 30 to be the column number, but the line to stay the same, but for a reason or another, the above just thinks my line number is 0, hence it resets the line to that value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash text absolute positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381937/bash-text-absolute-positioning)

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer to my own question, by moving the cursor at the beginning of line and then move it forward by 30 columns, as in this example:

```
\033[50D\033[30C My Text Goes Here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#-###--------------------{ Printf Functions }-----------------------------###-#
# If scroll occur lines numbers will shifted                                  |
Pxy() { printf "\e[${2};${1}H${3}" ;}            # from 0:0; $1 $2 $3"\n"     |
XY () { printf "\e[${2};${1}H${3}" ;}            # XY 10 10 'Hello World!'    |
Exy() { echo -en "\e[${2};${1}H${3}" >$(tty) ;}  # from 0:0; $1 $2 echo $3"\n"|
Line () { printf -v _L %$2s; printf -- "${_L// /$1}"; } # Line "+-*" 10       |
# Create sequence like {0..(X-1)}                                             |
Que () { printf -v _N %$1s; _N=(${_N// / 1}); printf "${!_N[*]}"; } # Que 10  |
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
function Text_@ () { printf "\e[${2};${1}H${3}${4}" ;} # $1 $2 $3"\n"         |
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
function H_line() { local Line=' ' #                                          |
builtin printf -v Line "%${2:-${COLUMNS:-`tput cols 2>&- || echo "80" `}}s" # |
echo -e "\033[G\033[2K${Line// /${1:-=}}" ;} #                                |
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#-###--------------------{ Movements Functions }--------------------------###-#
Linesup () { echo -n ""$'\033['$1'A'"" >$(tty) ;} #                           |
Linesdn () { echo -n ""$'\033['$1'B'"" >$(tty) ;} #                           |
#-### ------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Mrn() { echo -en ""$'\033['${1}C${2}"" >$(tty) ;}  # move right n             |
Mln() { echo -en ""$'\033['${1}D${2}"" >$(tty) ;}  # move left  n             |
Mdb() { echo -en ""$'\033['${1}E${2}"" >$(tty) ;}  # move down n begin line   |
Mub() { echo -en ""$'\033['${1}F${2}"" >$(tty) ;}  # move up n begin line     |
Mcn() { echo -en ""$'\033['${1}G${2}"" >$(tty) ;}  # move to column          |
#-### ------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#       echo move up  $1 right $2 $3"\n" no scroll                            |
Mhy() { echo -en "\e[${1}A\e[${2}C${3}" >$(tty) ;} #                          |
#       echo move down $1 right $2 $3"\n" no scroll                           |
Mdy() { echo -en "\e[${1}B\e[${2}C${3}" >$(tty) ;} #                          |
#-### --------------------{ Setup Functions }-----------------------------###-#
function Get_winsize() #                                                      |
{ shopt -s checkwinsize; ( : ); : || echo $LINES $COLUMNS ;} #                |
#-###---------------------------------------------------------------------###-#
function Get_cursor_pos() { declare -g ROW COL; Old_IFS=${IFS} #              |
stty -echo -echok; IFS=';' read -s -dR -p $'\E[6n' ROW COL; stty echo echok # |
IFS=${Old_IFS} ROW="${ROW#*[}" ;}; : || { echo "${ROW};${COL}" ;} #           |
#-###---------------------------------------------------------------------###-#

Test_movements ()
{
Line - 40; echo #
echo "         1         2         3         4"
echo "123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|"
{ echo -n "1"; Mcn "30" "30\n" ;}
{ echo -n "1"; Mrn "1" "3";  Mcn "30" "30"; Mln "12" "20\n" ;}
echo "123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|"
echo "         1         2         3         4"
Line - 40; echo #
}
 Test_movements
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

There's more than one way, but the simplest would be **`HPA`** (refer to [*XTerm Control Sequences*](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)):

```
CSI Pm `  Character Position Absolute  [column] (default = [row,1])
          (HPA).
```

For example

```
printf '\033[30`%s\n' "My Text Goes Here"
```

Further reading: [*ECMA-48:
Control Functions for Coded Character Sets*](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)

Answer (score -2):

Below are instructions on how to move your cursor within a bash script or determine the current location of your cursor within a bash script ( or any text file ) using the vi text editor from a bash shell ( i.e. terminal ).

First, you will want to open the bash script ( or any text file ) using the vi editor.

```
vi bashscript.sh
```

If you want to move the cursor to line 10 and column 2 within a bash script using the vi editor run the below command ( note you type ':' to enter a command ).

```
:cal cursor(10, 2)
```

If you want to see your current row and column within a bash script using the vi editor run the below command.

```
:echo "Row = " line('.') ", Col = " virtcol('.')
```